# Add HTML with variable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am trying to have my JavaScript print a variable along with some text, I have an example(it doesn’t work, I think...):

#### CSS

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
  @font-face {
  font-family: Superfont;
  src: url(Suplexmentary_Comic_NC.ttf);
  }
.name{
  font-size: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}
.message{
  font-family: Superfont;
}
```

#### Java

```
let addthistext = "hi"
document.getElementById("parentID").appendChild(<div class="container">
    <p class="name">member</P>
    <p class="message">text</p>
  </div>)
```

Could you try coming up with an answer?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Answer (score 2):

Almost correct, need to create new `element`

```js
let addthistext = "hi";
let el = document.createElement('p');
el.innerText = addthistext;
el.classList.add("text");
document.getElementById("parentID").appendChild(el)
```

```css
.text{
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

```html
<div id='parentID'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Dominik Matis, I would also like to add a class to it, please see the edit

Thank you again!

Comment: could you take a second look at the JavaScript, I added a `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that Dominik's Answer is the correct one if you want to go with pure javascript, but if you want to go with a JQuery solution ( which is much easier) try this:

```
$('#parentID').append('<p>addthistext</p>')
```